# Does the i5 processor in the 2011 iMac allow hyper threading?

Tags: hyper-threading

On the intel website, it says that the i5 processor uses hyper threading. Elsewhere on the internet I've read various conflicting reports. Can anyone give me a definitive answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not.

In this 2011 iMac unboxing, [the processor](http://www.techrepublic.com/photos/cracking-open-the-27-apple-imac-2011/6237041?seq=115&tag=siu-container;internal-source-marker_0.9834403330936571) is an 2500-S, and [according to Intel itself](http://ark.intel.com/products/52211/Intel-Core-i5-2500S-Processor-(6M-Cache-2_70-GHz)), this model does not support it.

[image]

Here's the info from Intel itself:

[image]

Basically, the desktop i5's don't support Hyper Threading. This is also explained [in this](http://www.macworld.com/article/159765/2011/05/imac2011.html) and several subsequent reports from MacWorld on the 2011 iMac.

Comment: [Here is a useful page](http://www.intel.com/en_UK/consumer/products/processors/compare-processors.htm?select=desktop#cont2) on the Intel site showing all Desktop i5's and if they support HT or not.

Comment: Also a good resource, thanks for sharing @HaydnWVN

Comment: Right. Thanks for that, i7 it is then.